# Tip Calculator jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple tip calculator with jquery. When I press the submit button, I recieve a javascript alert saying NaN. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I fix this? Thanks so much.

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="tip calculator" />
<meta name="keywords" content="tip, calculator" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="tipcalc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="entries">
    Enter Bill Amount: <input type="text" /> <br><br>
    Enter Tip Percent: <input type="text" /> <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Tip" id="submit" />
</div>
<script>
var total = $("#total").val();
var tip = $("#tip").val();
var amount = total + (tip / 100);
$("#submit").click(
function() {alert(amount);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to set the id tags for your inputs:

```
<div class="entries">
    Enter Bill Amount: <input id="total" type="text" /> <br><br>
    Enter Tip Percent: <input id="tip" type="text" /> <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Tip" id="submit" />
</div>
```

And use `parseFloat` to turn values into numbers:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());
   var tip = parseFloat($("#tip").val());
   var amount = total + (tip / 100);
   alert(amount);
});
```

Also, notice I moved your variables to the inside of your event handler.

Comment: Awesome. This did it. I had to change the amount variable to equal total + (tip / 100 * total) but other than that it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

you don't seem to have a div with an id of "total" or "tip",
replace:

```
Enter Bill Amount: <input type="text" /> <br><br>
Enter Tip Percent: <input type="text" /> <br><br>
```

with:

```
Enter Bill Amount: <input type="text" id="total"/> <br><br>
Enter Tip Percent: <input type="text" id="tip"/> <br><br>
```